# cloning single HDD to dynamic HDD (RAID1) ... what app can do it?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, raid, clone

I have a 1TB O/S disk and just installed matching 2TB disks in a RAID1 configuration via Win7 Disk Management.

Previously, I had used EASEUS Todo Backup to successfully and easily clone drives, but now I see it can't work with dynamic drives. Their beefier EaseUS Partition Master says it can clone from dynamic to singles, but not **singles to dynamic** (my need).

Does anybody know of a clone tool that can handle dynamic disks (RAID1), and specifically clone from singles to dynamic? Free/not free I don't care at this point...

I never guessed this would be a problem :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a complete failure. Win7 wouldn't even install onto the RAID1 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it won't clone it.  Pretty much any backup tool will work, as long as you turn off the sector-by-sector option.

For example, I've cloned many RAID to single disks and vice versa using Macrium's Reflect, Acronis, Windows Backup and also Norton's Ghost.

I'd try any one of those.

Comment: Reflect doesn't recognize the drive at all, though Win7 shows it in Computer without any trouble. I'm downloading the (large) Acronis 2012 trial now and will try that next.